# nginx URL rewrite using negative regex?

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to redirect requests to https in nginx, *unless* it is of the form HOST/ANY_STRING_OF_CHARS/END_OF_URI, e.g.:

http://host.org/about # no redirect

http://host.org/users/sign_in # redirects to https://host.org/users/sign_in

This apparently works in Apache, but I don't understand how the bang works (ignore if it doesn't really work):

```
RewriteRule !/([a-z]+)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

How can I do this in a nginx rewrite rule? This is not working as I'd hoped:

```
rewrite !/([a-z]+)$ https://$server_name$request_uri redirect;
```

This doesn't do the redirect either, in case I had the logic backwards:

```
rewrite /([a-z]+)$ https://$server_name$request_uri redirect;
```

Help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39549548/1642018

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sends a permanent redirect to the client:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite ^(/users/\w+)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
  ...
}
```

for negative match you could use:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/users/\w+$")
{
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm looking for a negative match, i.e. no redirect for a specific pattern, redirect for _everything_ else, not just requests with /users/ in it. Good call on `permanent`, I should be doing that.

Comment: I have added negative match for you.

Comment: Thank you! bonus points for a location block instead? I hear that's preferable to if, no?

Comment: You can't do negative match with location.

Answer (score 4):

```
set $test "0";
if ($request_uri ~ "condition") {
   set $test "1";
}
if ($test ~ "0") {
   return 301 redirect url;
}
```