# How to redirect in nginx if request URI does not contain certain words

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using nginx to serve static news-like pages.
On the top-level there is
`https://example.com/en/news/` with an overview of the articles.
Individual items have a URL similar to this: `https://example.com/en/news/some-article`

All URLs contain the language, i.e. `/en/` or `/de/`.
I would like to create a rule that redirects requests that **don't** contain the language to the correct URL (the language is mapped based on IP an available via `$lang`).

The following should work (`en` example):

```
/news/             --- redirect ---> /en/news/
/news/some-article --- redirect ---> /en/news/some-article
```

My attempts looked something like this

```
location ~* /news/.*$ {
    if ($request_uri !~* /(de|en)/$) {
        return 302 https://example.com/$lang/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

So far this resulted in infinite redirects.

Comment: Take a look at this post: [nginx URL rewrite using negative regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159108/nginx-url-rewrite-using-negative-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems overly complicated to me. And testing `$request_uri` with a trailing `$` will never match the rewritten URIs (hence the loop).

You could use a prefix `location` to only match URIs that begin with `/news/`.

Assuming that you have calculated a value for `$lang` elsewhere, this may work for you:

```
location ^~ /news/ {
    return 302 /$lang$request_uri;
}
```

The `^~` modifier is only necessary if you have regular expression `location` blocks within your configuration that may conflict. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Thanks, that helped - even avoids `if` which I think is even nicer.