# Nginx WSS (port 443) to WS (port 80) rewrite rule containing regex URL

Tags: nginx, websocket, proxy, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

### Apache

I have the following `RewriteRule` in the Apache web proxy server configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myserver.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@myserver.example.com
 
        # Rewrite rule for the WebSocket connection
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/            [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]
 
        # Logs for connections at port 443 (HTTPS/WSS)
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myserver.example.com-SSL-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myserver.example.com-SSL-access.log combined
 
        # HTTPS => HTTP redirect for requests to the application
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
 
        # Alias and certificate configuration
        ServerAlias myserver.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

(Maybe it can be even simplified to `RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ ws://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]`, I didn't check that.)

This configuration works fine and I successfully connect with the application behind the proxy server using HTTP and WebSockets, depending on which URL I use.

---

### Nginx

Now, I am trying to recreate the same behavior using Nginx.

I tried:

```
server {

       server_name myserver.example.com;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-access.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-error.log;

       rewrite ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ ws://localhost:8000/$1;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
       }


       listen [::]:443 ssl;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/privkey.pem;
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

and:

```
server {

       server_name myserver.example.com;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-access.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-error.log;

       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/$1;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
       }


       listen [::]:443 ssl;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/privkey.pem;
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

I also tried adding the following headers to the WebSocket's `location`:

```
       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/$1;
            
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }
```

and this rewrite rule clause:

```
      if ($request_uri ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/) {       
           rewrite (.*)  ws://localhost:8000/$1;
       }
```

For all above cases of the `nginx` configuration all requests are treated as HTTP requests in the application at `localhost:8000/`.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the following connection working, e.g., connecting from the browser using JavaScript:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://myserver.example.com/1234123/ws/graph/`);
```

I am not an expert on Nginx and the syntax for the rules is hardly documented, or I cannot find it. All suggestions are welcomed.

---

### Sources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159322/8877692
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#location-block-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague helped me with this one. Below I post the answer.

### The solution

The proper configuration is:

```
server {

       server_name myserver.example.com;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-access.log;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/myserver.example.com_SSL-error.log;

       # WebSocket support
       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }

       # HTTP proxy
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
       }


       listen [::]:443 ssl;
       listen 443 ssl;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.example.com/privkey.pem;
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

---

### What I did wrong

My mistake was that I tied:

```
       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
           ...
       }
```

and:

```
       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/$1;
           ...
       }
```

both of which will not work, with the former (note the **"/"** at the end of the URL line) resulting in an error:

```
    "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost-myserver.example.com.conf:10
```

Also note that a separate `location` must be there to handle "normal" HTTP requests, else the requests won't be proxied properly:

```
       ...

       # WebSocket support
       location ~ ^/[0-9]+/ws/graph/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
           ...
       }

       # HTTP proxy
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
       }

       ...
```